# Disable direct update on Worklight 6.2 doesn't working?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I have application deployed on worklight 6.2, and i want to disable the direct update from authenticationConfig.xml.
My customSecurityTest looks like that:

```
 <customSecurityTest name="SubscribeServlet">
    <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="disabled" step="0"/>
    <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="SubscribeServlet" />
</customSecurityTest>
<customSecurityTest name="AdapterSecurityTest">
    <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="disabled" step="0"/>
    <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="AdapterAuthRealm" />
</customSecurityTest>
```

But still the application check for updates when getting started. The mode **disabled** seems to be not working.

Comment: ios? android? windows phone?

Comment: I use the Android platform,
Server version: 6.2.0.00.20140613-0730

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: I have double-checked this and it is working fine.

I am using Worklight 6.2.0.01-20150102-1548
Steps I've taken:

1. Created a new project and application, and added the Android environment
2. Added the following custom security test in server\conf\authenticationConfig.xml:

   ```
   <customSecurityTest name="customTests">
           <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/>
           <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1"/>
           <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="perSession" step="1"/>
           <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
   ```
3. Applied the security test to the environment in apps\my-app\application-descriptor.xml:

   ```
   <android version="1.0" securityTest="customTests">
           <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="2"/>
       </customSecurityTest>
   ```
4. Added in common\js\main.js, in `wlCommonInit()`:

   ```
   function wlCommonInit(){
       WL.Client.connect({onSuccess: function() {alert("success");}, onFailure: function() {alert("failure");}});
   }
   ```
5. Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server
6. Run As > Android application

The application successfully connected to the server

7. Changed main.js to display another alert. Quit the app and re-opened it

A second alert was displayed.

8. Changed the alert text to some other text
9. In authenticationConfig.xml changed the mode from `perSession` to `disabled` and saved the file

The saving makes sure that the server takes the changes into account.
If you are using a remote server (and not the development server), **you must re-deploy the .war and .wlapp file for the change to be applied(!).**

10. Quit the app and re-opened it

No Direct Update request came in and the same previous second alert text was displayed.

Also verified again by changing the mode from `disabled` back to `perSession`. Quit the app and re-opened it - the updated alert was then displayed after the request for Direct Update.

---

The following security test name implies to me that this is a security test you have placed on an adapter procedure.

```
<customSecurityTest name="AdapterSecurityTest">
```

This will not make the application not-receive a Direct Update on application startup - because you did not put this security test on the *environment*, thus it will not be enacted on startup. You've only placed it on the adapte procedure (which is called only during `WL.Client.invokeProcedure`...).

You must also protect the environment itself. Add another custom "my-security-test" and put it on the environment node in application-descriptor.xml

For example:

```
<android version="1.0" securityTest="my-security-test">
```

Comment: thx for fast answer, but i still can't disable direct update, i will show you some parts of my config files application-descriptor.xml and authenticationConfix.xml
**application-descriptor.xml:**
`<android version="1.0" securityTest="my-security-test">`



  **authenticationConfix.xml:**
 `<customSecurityTest name="my-security-test">
  <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="disabled" step="1"/>
  <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
   <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="2"/>
 </customSecurityTest>`

Comment: this doesn't seems to work. I've created a customSecurityTest and defined in application-descriptor.xml...

Comment: @IdanAdar Wow, such a detailed answer! This is really something that the official documentation currently lacks.